# How to save and read user information (username ,password,and so on) by serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

Is write all User information to only a file ,or every user has a self file ? And how to write information or read information of someone?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step guide to basic serializaiton in java:

1. Import java.io.Serializable
2. List item

Get your data-containing class to implement Serializable.

```
    public class MyClass implements Serializable {
```

3. Use an Object I/O stream to read/write your objects
    from files.

Here is a great concise tutorial:
http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization